# Throwing exception from toString method

Tags: java, exception

I have a Java class pojo in which I want the Object.toString() method to return a JSON representation of the object. The users of toString() want JSON only. This is my toString().

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;

@Override
public String toString(){
    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    String json = null;
    try {
        json = ow.writeValueAsString(this);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}
```

The problem is that the above code will swallow the exception and allow execution to continue. To avoid such problems, we can either throw exception or re-throw the exception as an unchecked exception as mentioned here [Java - overriding Object's toString() method, but I have to throw exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011568/java-overriding-objects-tostring-method-but-i-have-to-throw-exceptions).

But, toString() does not allow us to throw exceptions. So, we can only throw an unchecked exception. 
The above link's selected answer says that "throwing exceptions from toString() is a really bad idea". It suggests to return a error string instead which seems bad to me because we are really just swallowing the exception. The other suggestion is to throw IllegalStateExcception instead. Is this the ideal exception to throw in this situation or should we throw another one ? Thanks.

**UPDATE :** I corrected a mistake in my code. The toString() method does not take a parameter.

Comment: `"But, toString() does not allow us to throw exceptions"` -- not true as this is not a classic `toString()` method as it takes a parameter, and so I see no problem with this method throwing whatever exception you desire.

Comment: @AndyTurner: better a checked exception, and declare the method as throwing this, no?

Comment: "The users of toString() want JSON only" that doesn't look right. Are you sure you understood your requirements correctly (and why does that `toString` method accept parameter)? Also should that representation be formatted in many lines? If yes what should be its indentation?

Comment: @Pshemo - The toString() method is just used for logging the expected response for an api. The pojo i talked about is a Java representation of that Json response. We don't use the toString() of the pojo for anything else.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Does the 2nd approach in this answer sound correct ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42011744/3184475

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Sorry, I made a mistake while copying my code into this question. The toString() method is standard and does not take any argument.

Comment: Please attempt to be more careful as our time on this site is all volunteer time, and no sense in our wasting our time chasing rabbits down the wrong hole.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - agree. sorry about that. If you downvoted, I request you to please undo it. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would also advise against throwing an exception from `toString`. The method is often used for debugging purposes (whether its via `System.out` or with a debugger). Throwing excpetions just complicates things and makes everything harder.

Instead, I would suggest to add a `toJSON` method that throws either a JsonProcessingException or a (subclass of) RuntimeException, and implement toString such that it calls toJson, catches all exceptions and returns the error message in such cases.

Comment: thanks. I wonder why we are delegating the json conversion to toJson() and then letting toString() catch all exceptions and return the error messages. Can't we do all that directly inside toString() - convert to json and if there is an exception, then return the error ?

Comment: By keeping a separate toJSON method, you still have the option to do proper error handling if needed. You should always try to implement only one thing per method. In this case, toJSON converts to JSON, if possible(!); while toString always returns a String.