# Is it a good practice to catch a variety of specific exceptions along with one generic catch-all exception?

Tags: java, exception

**General problem**

When writing a service method, there are advantages and disadvantages to throwing many exceptions versus abstracting them into a generic `ServiceException`. If you throw many exceptions, then you tell the client what exactly went wrong, so that the client can deal with the error more sensibly. If you abstract them into one `ServiceException` (e.g. via [exception wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972893/what-is-exception-wrapping-in-java)), then you are hiding the details of what went wrong, which can be useful in some scenarios but harmful in others.

For example, it can be useful to hide the details of went wrong in a   DAO class, by throwing a generic `DaoException`. This way clients don't have to know whether you are reading from a file, a web service, or a relational database. But let's say you are validating user input, and there are at least four things that can go wrong with the user input. Isn't it more sensible in the latter case to throw four different exceptions, one for each thing that went wrong with the validation?

**My specific problem**

In my current project, I am working  on a service method that saves a tree-like structure into a relational database. It has to validate the tree, and there are at least four things that can be wrong with the tree. There can be a duplicate node, or a node can be missing its mandatory X, Y, Z fields. Thus it makes sense for the service method to throw four different exceptions: `DuplicateNodeException`, `MissingXException`, `MissingYException`, `MissingZException`.

But the service method also uses the DAO class, which throws a `DataAccessException` via JdbcTemplate. I would like to know how to handle this `DataAccessException`. Would it make sense to wrap it as a `ManagerException` and then again as a `ServiceException`, and handle it as a `ServiceException`? Then I would be mixing both approaches of (a) throwing specific, descriptive exceptions and (b) throwing generic wrapper exceptions. Is a good idea to mix these approaches here?

The reason I ask is because it seems a little odd to me to catch these four validation-related exceptions and then in addition to catch a generic, nondescript `ServiceException`. It seems odd because the `ServiceException` is so abstracted that there's no way to tell at first glance what went wrong, you would have to check the log and read the exception message, or navigate the call hierarchy in the code. I'm asking, then, to verify that it's indeed a good practice, or common, or sensible, to mix these two approaches, because intuitively it seems strange to me. Are there any parallels in core Java where both approaches to exception handling are used in the same method?

**Possible solution (per Andreas's answer)**

Would it make sense to handle exceptions like this in my Service class? Below is some pseudocode presenting a possible solution. This way I'm not creating a useless, checked, nondescript ServiceException, but I do have a catch-all for unchecked exceptions (by catching Exception at the end). What are your thoughts on this solution?

```
class HttpService {

    private Service service;

    // ...

    public HttpServiceResponse saveTree(Node root) {
        try {
            service.saveTree(root);  
        } catch (DuplicateNodeException e) {
            return HttpServiceResponse.failure(DUPLICATE_NODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (MissingXException e) {
            return HttpServiceResponse.failure(MISSING_X_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (MissingYException e) {
            return HttpServiceResponse.failure(MISSING_Y_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (MissingZException e) {
            return HttpServiceResponse.failure(MISSING_Z_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return HttpServiceResponse.failure(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The advice of *Effective Java* is to throw exceptions appropriate to the abstraction.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks, that's good advice. Did you downvote? If so why?

Comment: I did not downvote.

Comment: Have you considered defining those exceptions as unchecked and letting the client to decide which ones to handle or ignore.

Comment: @tsolakp Yes, I have. But the exception I am trying to handle appropriately is an (unchecked) DataAccessException thrown by JdbcTemplate in my DAO class. Now, if the manager and service layers both throw a DataAccessException, then that's not appropriate to the abstraction, per Andy Turner's advice. And if the DAO class were to switch to a file or a web service, then all of a sudden I'd have to catch an IOException or a RemoteException in the manager and service layers. That's why I thought to abstract it as a ManagerException in the manager layer and a ServiceException in the service layer.

Comment: While the JDBC API throws *checked* `SQLException`, the `JdbcTemplate` wrappers those with *unchecked* `DataAccessException`, so callers don't need to specifically declare and handle them. There is no need to wrapper the `DataAccessException` with a `ServiceException`. If the service does other stuff that throws *checked* exceptions, those should be similarly wrapped with specific exceptions, not a generic `ServiceException`. The caller doesn't care about those exception, because there is nothing the caller can do about them, but don't just wrap all exceptions into a generic `ServiceException`

Comment: @Andreas That makes sense to me. I updated my question with a possible solution. What do you think of this solution? Does it agree with what you are saying?

Comment: @ktm5124 Is `DuplicateNodeException` or `MissingXException` unchecked exception? If they are then why handle and wrap them with `HttpServiceResponse.failure`?

Comment: @tsolakp `DuplicateNodeException` and `MissingXException` are checked exceptions. I'm wrapping them with HttpServiceResponse.failure so I can return an intelligent error message to the AJAX call that calls my service.

Comment: @ktm5124 I would declare them as unchecked unless you cant change the source code for them. Usually you rarely define custom checked exceptions.

Comment: @tsolakp But I want the caller to act on them, since they're recoverable exceptions, so it makes sense to declare them as checked, doesn't it? See the ten tips at the end of this article: https://blog.takipi.com/ignore-checked-exceptions-all-the-cool-devs-are-doing-it-based-on-600000-java-projects/.

Comment: Wrapping an exception most certainly does not hide the details of what went wrong.  The whole purpose of exception chaining is to preserve the underlying exception.  Therefore, wrapping underlying exceptions in an exception type appropriate for your service is a very good practice.  (Note that your example code does not do this, and instead throws away the exceptions it catches, which in my opinion makes it a bad practice.)

Answer (score 3):

Most exceptions should be *unchecked*, because they are not really actionable, i.e. there is really nothing the caller can do about it, other than passing it along, or logging it and failing whatever operation is currently in progress. Only exceptions that are actionable and requires such caller action should be checked, which is pretty rare.

If all the exceptions are unchecked, it means that the caller can do with a single catch-all. Since the service layer no longer needs to wrapper exceptions from e.g. the DAO layer, the caller *can* catch and handle specific exceptions, if desired.